# Does Office 365 Small Business Pro support multiple domains?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I am currently looking into migrating over to Office 365 from our SBS 2008 server. I understand that I can tie my installation to a specific domain like say emample.com and then have my email address as something@example.com and then also my sharepoint installation as www.example.com.

That's great, but I have a number of other domains that I need to port across as well that are currently supported by our Microsft Exchange system. We have another domain that is closely related to example.com, say examples.com that people sometimes type in in error. We don't want to lose those emails. What's the best solution? Should I just keep the examples.com domain outside of the Office 365 system? Or, is there some way I can support those emails in the same system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your Office 365 email tenant can be authoritative for multiple DNS domains.